# How to convert HashTable values in to 2D Array

Tags: java

```
package com.xchanging.selenium.utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

    public static void readExcel(String sheetName, String testCaseName)
            throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook sourceBook = new XSSFWorkbook("./TestCases.xlsx");
        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = sourceBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        int testCaseStartRow = 0;
        while (!sourceSheet.getRow(testCaseStartRow).getCell(0)
                .getRichStringCellValue().toString().equals(testCaseName)) {
            testCaseStartRow++;
        }
        System.out.println("testCaseStartingRow: " + testCaseStartRow);

        int testCaseStartColumn = 0;
        int headerRow = testCaseStartRow + 1;
        int keyRow = headerRow + 1;
        while (sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(testCaseStartColumn) != null) {
            testCaseStartColumn++;
        }
        int lastColumn = testCaseStartColumn - 1;
        System.out.println("Header Row: " + headerRow);
        System.out.println("Key Row: " + keyRow);
        int parameters = lastColumn + 1;
        System.out.println("NO. of Parameters: " + parameters);
        Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        Object[][] testData = new Object[0][lastColumn];
        for (int j = 0; j <= lastColumn; j++) {
            int cellType = sourceSheet.getRow(keyRow).getCell(j).getCellType();
            if (cellType == 0) {
                String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                        .toString();
                String value = Double.toString(sourceSheet.getRow(keyRow)
                        .getCell(j).getNumericCellValue());
                table.put(key, value);
            } else if (cellType == 1) {
                String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                        .toString();
                String value = sourceSheet.getRow(keyRow).getCell(j).toString();
                table.put(key, value);

            } else if (cellType == 2) {
                String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                        .toString();
                String value = sourceSheet.getRow(keyRow).getCell(j)
                        .getRawValue().toString();
                table.put(key, value);

            } else if (cellType == 4) {
                String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                        .toString();
                String value = Boolean.toString(sourceSheet.getRow(keyRow)
                        .getCell(j).getBooleanCellValue());
                table.put(key, value);

            } else {
                String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                        .toString();
                String value = "";
                table.put(key, value);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have stored Excel Sheet Parameters and Values in to HashTable.. Can I change this in to 2D array and able to acceess the values by keys??

The reason why i need to change 2D array is, TestNG supports only 2D array object.

Comment: You mean like a `n x 2`-array?

Comment: yes.. Object [][] in this formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simply way to do this is by iterating over the values:

```
public static<T,Q> Object[][] toArray (Map<T,Q> map) {
    if(map == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Object[][] result = new Object[map.size()][];
    int index = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<T,Q> e : map.entrySet()) {
        result[index++] = new Object[] {e.getKey(),e.getValue()};
    }
    return result;
}
```

This [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/hK) demonstrates a testcase.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, below sample will be you ;

```
Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable();
    map.put("A", "B");
    map.put("C", "D");
    Object[][] arr = new Object[map.size()][2];
    Set entries = map.entrySet();
    Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

    int i = 0;

    while (entriesIterator.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

        arr[i][0] = mapping.getKey();
        arr[i][1] = mapping.getValue();

        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly neatly with a stream in Java 8:

```
    String[][] arrays = new String[map.size()][2];
    arrays = map.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
        String[] row = {entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()};
        return row;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(arrays);
```